# Signing a web form - options for digital signature

Tags: asp.net, webforms, digital-signature

I am developing web form equivalents of paper based forms.

On the paper form people get the option to sign the form with their signature.

In ASP.NET what are the options for a digital equivalent.

Comment: What kind of equivalent were you thinking about? Do the end users understand digital certificates? Do they have them? Do they know how to use them? If not, how do you intend to educate them on the matter?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest some pages, if we talking for the same think.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163434.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480189.aspx

http://www.microsoft.com/uk/msdn/nuggets/nugget/224/Using-CardSpace-with-ASPNET.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It may be too late, but for the sake of others who are looking for the same thing as me - try [JSignature](https://willowsystems.github.io/jSignature/#/about/) JavaScript plugin. Here is the [ReadMe](https://github.com/willowsystems/jSignature/blob/master/README.md) from github. Hope it helps.